# Setting the max and min value for delta in slick2d

Tags: java, slick2d

Though it looks funny in my game, I have some basic rts movement where you right click and the unit moves there. But sometimes when I run the game the unit moves much slower than normal but nothing has been changed in the code (other times the unit moves much faster). When I open up more programs the speed returns to normal but if i'm just running Netbeans I get super slow movement.

I have a feeling it has something to do with the delta value(not really sure) for updating but as i'm new to slick2d I don't know where to start with fixing the problem.

So my question is, can I limit the delta value so it can't update too slow or too fast and is delta even my problem?

http://pastebin.com/fRndGE2p //Main class

http://pastebin.com/KJ8W3134 //PlayerStats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see now. You did not turned on the VSync. 
 
*Note: The VSync limits your framerate to your monitors refresh rate (usually 60fps).* 

Ohh and the maximum/minimum update intervals are in *miliseconds*.

**So the following example makes the game very laggy:**

```
app.setVSync(true);                     // Turn VSync
app.setMaximumLogicUpdateInterval(200); // Max. 200 miliseconds can pass
app.setMinimumLogicUpdateInterval(100); // Min. 100 miliseconds must pass
```

So i think you have to play around the numbers to make it optimal.

*But, this is not what you need :D* 

I saw this:

```
player_X = player_X + velocityX;
player_Y = player_Y + velocityY;
```

So this was your code, to update the positions of the player.
You must use the delta number.

```
 public void update(GameContainer gc, int delta)
```

As you can see the delta is a pre defined integer. The delta contains the time that passed between two updates. So after this you should multiply everything with delta.

**Check this:**

```
player_X += velocityX * delta;
player_Y += velocityY * delta;

// The '+=' means player_X = player_X + something (if you did not know)
```

*Note: If the player moves slowly after the change, then simply multiply it with a number like this:*

```
player_X += velocityX * delta * 1.5f;
player_Y += velocityY * delta * 1.5f;
```

***Example:***

> [The Runnable Jar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjbcfb44zt9bbvi/test.jar) 
>   [MainComponent.java](http://pastebin.com/RMqzXVvZ) 
>   [GameState.java](http://pastebin.com/PYFmL32D)

This is a self made fast and simple example for you. Try it out, taste the source code:D 
Oh and this distance calculating method makes the player shaky.

Comment: Cool, it does get rid of the slow movement but it messes up the movement code similar to your problem where it doesn't move to its proper point.

Comment: I added an example for you

Comment: Yay! finally got it after using the code you supplied in the example and I fixed the unit just barely missing its target too.